# Backup/Restore SQL Server 2016 LocalDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups, localdb, sql-server-2014-localdb

I have SQL Server 2016 LocalDB (`.mdf` file) and I want make backup of my database. I use the code shown below, but it does not work. I tested all code that exists in stackoverflow, but none of them worked.

Here is my code (this code works perfectly on SQL Server 2014 but does not work on localdb):

```
SqlConnection connect;
string con = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database\ClassSRM.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
connect = new SqlConnection(con);
connect.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database " + Application.StartupPath + @"\Database\ClassSRM.mdf" + " to disk ='" + strFileName + "'", connect);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The connection or the backup? Please post the exception trace created when running the code.

Comment: connection is ok backup not work

Comment: It shouldn't work, because you need to specify the database name, not the .MDF file name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql